# Task.Run in c# slows entire site after a few queues

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a task that runs on request by the user to create a report.  The idea is they click the submit button and it queues the export in the background.  I have it working just fine, but when someone queues 4 or more exports the entire site/application slows to a crawl.

This is how I'm calling the task

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Export(ExportData exportData)
{
    //var t = Task.Run(() => RunExport(exportData));
    var company = GlobalVariables.CompanyID;
    var client = GlobalVariables.Client;
    var userId = GlobalVariables.OwnerID;
    var URL= GlobalVariables.URL;

    var invoiceList = GetExportInvoices(exportData, company, client);

    if (!invoiceList.Any())
    {
        return Json("FAILURE", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        RunExport(exportData, company, client, userId, URL);
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    //await RunExport(exportData);
    return Json("SUCCESS", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The task itself lives in a void

```
public void RunExport(ExportData exportData, int company, string client, string userId, string URL)
{
    var db = GetDBConn();
        string exception = null;
        bool fileAdded = false;
        string path = null;
        string fileName = null;

        try
        {
            ReturnReportValue retVal = new ReturnReportValue();

            ExportRpts rpt;
            SetExportRpts(exportData.ReportName, out rpt, company, client, db);

            var invoiceList = GetExportInvoices(exportData, company, client);

            switch (rpt.ReportType)
            {
                case 1:
                    retVal.ValuesMatch = true;
                    retVal.ReportFileName = ExportLD(rpt, invoiceList, company, client, db, userId);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    retVal = ExportGL(rpt, invoiceList, company, client, userId);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            path = retVal.ReportFileName;
            fileName = exportData.ReportName;
            var reportType = rpt.ReportType;
            // Add file to download table

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            {
                var newExport = new ExportExports();

                newExport.ClientID = client;
                newExport.CompanyID = company;
                newExport.UserID = userId;
                newExport.ExportName = fileName;
                newExport.ExportLocation = path;
                newExport.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                newExport.ReportType = reportType;

                db.Add(newExport);
                db.SaveChanges();

                fileAdded = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception = e.ToString();
        }
}
```

Am I running the task incorrectly?  When I put an await in front of the `Task.Run` it waits until the task is done instead of kicking off the background task and letting the user move forward.

Comment: If you want to run logic in the background, then the best place for that is to have a completely separate application to run it. This is often a Windows service, but could also be something like Azure functions etc. Your web application would enqueue the job. This might be using something like Hangfire, or a REST call to the service, or putting a message onto a message queue, like Azure Service Bus or RabbitMQ. Don't do long processing directly within a web server process, it's not designed for that.

Comment: Is RunExport doing any I/O bound processes?  It would really help to see what its actually doing, seeing is you are deadlocking...

Comment: do you host on IIS? there are various settings in IIS configuration to tweak how worker processes are allocated to requests. use also the many performance counters of ASP.NET runtime to see what actually happens.

Comment: @maccettura I am definitly doing I/O bound operations. I'm accessing the database, doing calculations, and building an excel report.

Comment: @TheDizzle We cant really help you unless we see the RunExport code.  I can already see you arent using async/await properly (nothing is being awaited, you arent using async/Task all the way down the chain, etc)

Comment: I've added the code, it goes into deeper and deeper methods.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to run this logic in a process outside of your web application?

Comment: @mason It could be done.  I was trying to fix this instead of going down that road, but it looks like I'm going to have to.

Comment: You absolutely should go down that road. This logic doesn't belong in a web application. You can fix this code up and make it run better and follow all the async principles, but it still wouldn't belong within your web application. There's *lots* of ways to go about moving this into its own process. But I've had good luck running [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) within a [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) Windows service.

Comment: Find out what resource is oversubscribed. If it's IO or CPU then async or an out of process architecture are not going to fix it. If the thread pool if oversubscribed then either go async or increase the thread pool limits.